# error while booting on elitebook8570

Tags: boot, clock, tpm

When I reboot I get an error

```
pci 0000:00:01.0: ASPM: Could not configure common clock
tpm_tis 00:01: A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
```

and when run `dmesg|grep TPM` I get

```
[    4.788710] tpm_tis 00:01: 1.2 TPM (device-id 0xB, rev-id 16)
[    5.028712] tpm_tis 00:01: TPM is disabled/deactivated (0x7)
[    5.128725] tpm_tis 00:01: A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
[    5.128797] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass
```

Is this a cause for concern and can I do something about it?

Answer (score 2):

**TPM**

TPM stands Trusted Platform Module and you can read more about it on Wikipedia ([TPM on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module)). The chip when present on the motherboard is used for securely producing cryptographic keys and securing the hardware components. Several laptop motherboards (and many desktop boards) have such TPM chips.
The message you receive means: Either the chip is available but not recognized or it is absent. The message itself is harmless.

*For your system*, from the specs I see that there is a TPM chip (ver 1.2) onboard.

You can check in your BIOS under security or trusted computing section for TPM and deactivate it. Most probably this will stop the errors.

---

**ASPM**

ASPM stands for Active State Power Management whose purpose is to save power in order to extend battery life on portable devices like laptops. It instructs PCIe components to go to low power mode to save power. The parameters controlling ASPM are controllable (which by default should be on ON state).

To set the parameter for ASPM you can

- First understand how to try entering kernel boot parameter [here on Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters).
- Next you can try temporarily adding the boot parameter to resolve your issue. You will need try out several parameters and get the one which works for you.

These are the kernel parameters which you can try :

Disable ASPM:

```
pcie_aspm=off
```

Use default firmware configuration:

```
pcie_aspm=default
```

Disables ASPM and clock power management (bad for battery life):

```
pcie_aspm=performance
```

Highest power saving mode, enable ASPM and clock power management:

```
pcie_aspm=powersave
```

Force ASPM on:

```
pcie_aspm=force
```

Force ASPM on while trying to maximize saving power:

```
pcie_aspm=force pcie_aspm.policy=powersave
```

Once you got it working make the change permanent according to the link attached (for kernel boot parameter).

Comment: This solved the TPM error. The ASPM error however, is still present.

Comment: You can act in BIOS for ASPM too. Likely you will not find the "ASPM" caption exactly...

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally I also experienced this problem.
I enabled the `secure boot` option in the BIOS.
After restarting, the problem was solved.